# Reactive Extensions OperationCancelled exception on Enumerable.Range / Observable.FromAsync

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, system.reactive, rx.net

I have the below code which is pulling data from a REST paginated API.

When using reactive extensions, it gets near to the end of the downloads (i.e. page 1,636 out of the known target 1,653, the exact count it gets to depends on concurrent fetches with higher concurrency resulting in lower page count of the known target)., and then my receive function throws a `OperationCancelled` exception (however i never set my cancellation token source).

It is like `Select` is cancelling my function somehow but only near the end of the pagination requests or the observable terminates and then kills off my observable, i think (but new to rx.net).

This is not a rate limit issue either, does this with one download at a time (`MaxConcurrentDownloads` set to 1).

Any ideas what i am doing wrong please with the below?

```
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var api = new PolygonWebApi(httpClient, this.apiKey);
var list = new List<TickerV2>();
var start = DateTime.Now;

// get first page
var response = await api.GetTickersAsync(BatchSize, 1, this.cts.Token);
list.AddRange(response.Tickers);
var pages = (response.Count + BatchSize - 1) / BatchSize;
                
var query = Enumerable
                .Range(2, pages - 1)
                .ToObservable()
                .Select(page => Observable.FromAsync(() =>
                {
                    return api
                            .GetTickersAsync(BatchSize, page, this.cts.Token)
                            .ContinueWith( x => new TickersResponseWithPage(page, x.Result));
                }))
                .Merge(MaxConcurrentDownloads);

query.Subscribe((response) =>
{
    this.logger.LogInformation($"adding {response.TickersResponse.Tickers.Length} records from page {response.Page}");
    list.AddRange(response.TickersResponse.Tickers);
});
await query.ToTask(this.cts.Token);
                
var duration = DateTime.Now - start;
this.logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(UpdateTickersWorker)} downloaded {list.Count:n0} in {duration.Humanize()}");
```

**Additional info if required, sequential test prove calls to API are OK and return all 1,653 pages**

```
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var api = new PolygonWebApi(httpClient, this.apiKey);
var list = new List<TickerV2>();
var start = DateTime.Now;


// get first page
var response = await api.GetTickersAsync(BatchSize, 1, this.cts.Token);
list.AddRange(response.Tickers);
var pages = (response.Count + BatchSize - 1) / BatchSize;

// read from second page
for (var page = 2; page <= pages && this.cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested == false; page++)
{
    response = await api.GetTickersAsync(BatchSize, page, this.cts.Token);
    list.AddRange(response.Tickers);
    this.logger.LogInformation($"adding {response.Tickers.Length} records from page {page}");
}

var duration = DateTime.Now - start;
this.logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(UpdateTickersWorker)} downloaded {list.Count} in {duration.Humanize()}");
```

**UPDATE**

I modified the below to stop the repeating pages and seems to have resolved the repeating issue:

```
IObservable<IList<TickerV2>> query =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () => new HttpClient(),
            hc =>
                from first_response in Observable.FromAsync(ct => PolygonWebApi.GetTickersAsync(hc, this.apiKey, BatchSize, 1, ct))
                let pages = (first_response.Count + BatchSize - 1) / BatchSize
                from trwp in
                    Observable
                        .Range(2, pages - 1)
                        .Select(page =>
                            Observable
                                .FromAsync(ct => PolygonWebApi.GetTickersAsync(hc, this.apiKey, BatchSize, page, ct))
                                .Select(r => new TickersResponseWithPage(page, r)))
                        .Merge(MaxConcurrentDownloads)
                        .StartWith(new TickersResponseWithPage(1, first_response))
                from tv2 in trwp.TickersResponse.Tickers
                select tv2)
        .ToList();

list = await query.ToTask(this.cts.Token);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a lot of weird mixing of synchronous code, enumerables, with Rx and with Tasks. All of that makes for a big mess when debugging. You should pick a monad and stay in it the whole time - don't mix them.

Can you please try this pure Rx version of your code and let me know what kind of results you get? Please append to the end of your question and don't change what it there.

```
IObservable<IList<TickerV2>> query =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () => new HttpClient(),
            hc =>
                from first_response in Observable.FromAsync(ct => api.GetTickersAsync(BatchSize, 1, ct))
                let pages = (first_response.Count + BatchSize - 1) / BatchSize
                from trwp in
                    Observable
                        .Range(2, pages - 1)
                        .SelectMany(page =>
                            Observable
                                .FromAsync(ct => api.GetTickersAsync(BatchSize, page, ct))
                                .Select(r => new TickersResponseWithPage(page, r)))
                        .StartWith(new TickersResponseWithPage(1, first_response))
                from tv2 in trwp.TickersResponse.Tickers
                select tv2)
        .ToList();

IList<TickerV2> list = await query;
```

---

Here's how to create the `api` object in a `Defer`:

```
IObservable<IList<TickerV2>> query =
    Observable
        .Defer(() =>
        {
            var api = new PolygonWebApi(httpClient, this.apiKey);
            return
                Observable
                    .Using(... as above ...)
                    .ToList();
        });
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! About to implement this what would one do with the API object instantiation  new PolygonWebApi(httpClient, this.apiKey); as I am unsure if that goes under Using() call chain (as I doesn't implement IDisposable)

Comment: @morleyc - If it doesn't need to be disposed then you can just create it before you create the observable. Better yet, wrap it in a `Defer` call.

Comment: @morleyc - I just noticed a mistake in my query that's going to repeat the first response. I can't fix it right now, but I'll try to get to it later today.

Comment: @morleyc - It's fixed.

Comment: thank you! Can i use `Merge(MaxConcurrentDownloads)` to limit as before, and anything I need to do with regards to bailing out the loop quickly in event of CancellationToken being set?

Comment: To use `Merge` replace the `SelectMany` with `Select` and add the `Merge`.

Comment: Just use your `.ToTask` trick if you want to cancel waiting for the observable, i.e. `IList<TickerV2> list = await query.ToTask(this.cts.Token);`.

Comment: sorry to be a pain, the code above is repeating the first 50 over and over (despite downloading the correct number of pages) so data is repeated. Any ideas please? I am trying a fix right now with `.Select(r => new TickersResponseWithPage(page, r)))`

Comment: @morleyc - You might need to post your current code to the question - please put it at the end using a `----` to separate it from the existing content.

Comment: @morleyc - THank you for the update. I can't see an issue with the query. You might need to put a few `.Do(x = { ... })` debug operators in there to see what's happening. Usually when you get repeated values you should put a further `Defer(() => { ... })` around the observable that is repeating.

Comment: Yes sorry should have mentioned, with the update swapping from ` .Select(r => new TickersResponseWithPage(page, first_response)))` to `.Select(r => new TickersResponseWithPage(page, r)))` resolved the issue, thanks for the support. I may have some RX work if you do assignments, please ping an email to @gmail.com with my username in front! Thanks again

Comment: @morleyc - An easy mistake to make when you can't run the code. Sorry. I've updated my answer. If you need to contact you can try my username at gmail too.